# Android - How to sort a Media query by path?

Tags: java, android, sql

I am trying to query the Android Media storage for audio files, and sort the results by file path. How should i do this?

My code is:

```
  mQueryHandler = new AsyncQueryHandler(getContentResolver(), this);
  mQueryHandler.startQuery(
        -1,
        null,
        Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        AudioFilesQuery.PROJECTION,
        null,
        null,
        AudioFilesQuery.SORT_ORDER);
```

And AudioFilesQuery looks like this:

```
private interface AudioFilesQuery {
    // if i delete Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString(), it works.
    String[] PROJECTION = {
            Media._ID, Media.TITLE, Media.ALBUM, Media.ARTIST
    };

    int TITLE = 1;
    int ALBUM = 2;
    int ARTIST = 3;
    // This is wrong, because it sorts by the path, that includes the filename.

    String SORT_ORDER = Media.DATA + " ASC";
}
```

Or is this impossible/ineffective using an SQL query? Should i rather get the whole DB, and sort it manually in JAVA?